# How do you get hover/active to work on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I made a site with an image gallery that shows you a white card with some information about each image if you move your mouse over the image. The site is live and it works perfectly on desktop computers but if you try to use it on a mobile device, nothing happens when you click on the images. Its weird to me because when I use live web server and inspect the page, it appears to work on mobile but it didn't work after I deployed everything to GitHub.

I was looking up this issue and saw people say that instead of just using hover, you also need to add :active to the element that you're going to be clicking on with the mobile device so I did that but it still isn't working.

What should I change in the CSS?

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.image-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.image-gallery .image-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-gallery .image-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.image-gallery .image-box .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fafaf2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .overlay {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover,
.image-box:active .overlay {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details {
  text-align: center;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .title {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .category {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .details .title {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover,
.image-box:active .details .title {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover .details .category {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box:hover,
.image-box:active .details .category {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s ease;
}

.image-gallery .image-box .details .title a,
.image-gallery .image-box .details .category a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-gallery">
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200" alt="painting">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="details">
        <h3 class="title" style="color:black">
          Piece 1
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: I was able to fix it by just adding tabindex="0" to the div with the class called image gallery. Thank you to everyone who tried to help

Comment: your code seems to work fine on mobile, the first click triggers the popup for me. Sure the issue isn't something else?

Comment: @LS_ It looks like it works fine when I check it in devtools, but on the actual deployed website it doesn't work at all. I've tried all the other suggestions that you guys have posted here and looked at a couple of youtube videos and nothing has fixed it. This seems like it should be really simple so I just don't know what the issue is

Comment: can you share a link to the live website?

Comment: @LS_ https://glittartstudio.com/

Comment: just checked, it works fine on my mobile device, when I click the boxes the popup appears same as desktop. Which mobile device has the issue?

Comment: @LS_ I'm looking at it on my Iphone SE 2020 and nothing happens when you click on the images

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile doesn't have a mouse that you can hover with, so try using `:focus` instead of `:hover` or `:active`, and insert the code inside a media query (example below), so it'll only show for mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) {
/* code here */
}
```